# Shorten barplot in ggplot2 dodge_position

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I tried to perform a ggplot2 geom barplot using the dodge position parameter comparing two different conditions. However, if one of the two condition has frequncy 0, while the other one is > 0, the bar occupies both position. So I would like to shorten it with a smaller base length. This example will be easier to understand:

[image]

and my code:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df_plot2, aes(x=Var1, y=perc,fill=TYPE))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position='dodge')+
  labs(y="Percentage", x="Gene Ontologies") +
  theme_classic()+
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Transcripts of:", values=c("#ff6c00","grey20")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1), text = element_text(size = 16))
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you know what is causing the "spread" your one bar? what value is missing is it `NA` or zero or what. When I've had this in the past I  have used something along the lines of `geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge2(width = 1, preserve = "single", padding = 0), width = 0.9)` but I just knocked up a dummy data frame with an NA value to attempt to replicate the plot you had but your code worked fine. Do you have a reproducible example?

Comment: You have the same issue to the right of the plot with orange bars.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the `preserve = single` option to `position_dodge`

```
geom_bar(position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single"))
```

https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html